# Excel 2010 external workbook data source select table dialog has worksheets listed twice

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with 2 worksheets (daily, monthly) where each sheet contains 1 table. I am attempting to use this file as an external data source for a Pivot Table in another Excel workbook. When I create the connection I get a 'Select Table' dialog with each worksheet listed twice (daily, daily$, monthly, monthly$). I am trying to determine the difference between the sheets with and without the dollar sign, but have not been able to find the answer.

Comment: What happens if you select one as opposed to the other?

Comment: I don't notice a difference by selecting one over the other. I'm just curious if I'm missing something that could cause a problem later on down the road.

Comment: I could not find any documentation specific to it. Typically a `$` indicates an absolute reference. In this case, I am unsure.